# Bootstrap .form-control and RecurlyJS iframe

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, recurly

Thank you for your kind reading my question.  I have trouble in aligning layout of Recurly subscription form.

In the screenshot, the first 4 items are using .form-control which has  inside it. These s are loaded by Recurly JS code after page is loaded.

I tried to make sure height: 32px for those element as well, but I could not figure out why the height of gaps differ than the below ones. I want them to be same as the below ones.

http://paulz.dev.biznessapps.com/global/signup_subscribe?plan=mobileapp59

[image: Signup Form]

I used Recurly JS v4.
https://js.recurly.com/v4/recurly.js

Thank you!
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customise styling on input fields as in here.

https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1#section-styling-card-fields

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
  iframe {
        height: 26px!important;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't like using !important property.

Comment: ok, if you are able to edit iframe so put this value in iframe like this              <iframe src="" border="0" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="height: 26px; width: 100%; background: transparent;">

Comment: I'm afraid I can not modify <iframe> because it is loaded by recurly js.

Comment: I have reduced the margin of the container to fit overall height.